# Custom Column Names in OpenCSV using BeanToCsv

Tags: java, opencsv

I am using OpenCSV BeanToCsv to dump a list of beans to a csv file. Everything is working however it creates the column names from the field names in the bean I am using. How do I change the column names that get created in the csv?

**Example Column Mapping:**

```
String[] columns = new String[] { "projectId", "patientFirstName", "patientLastName"};

//But I actually want the column for projectId to be "PROJECT_ID" in the
//.csv file and patientFirstName to be "PATIENT_FIRST_NAME".
```

There has to be some obvious easy way to do this but I just don't see it. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Does [OpenCsv writes wrong column names with BeanToCsv + HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778223/opencsv-writes-wrong-column-names-with-beantocsv-headercolumnnametranslatemapp) help?

Comment: Not that I can tell.

Comment: Are you sure? The link references a class that "Expands on HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy by allowing the user to pass in a map of column names to bean names. This way the fields in the bean do not have to match the fields in the csv file."

Comment: Ok, seems a little hackish but I have it going. Really surprised if there isn't an out of the box way of doing this.

Comment: Sounds good. Want to post some example code?