# How to get the exact name in @CsvBindByName?

Tags: java, opencsv

When using OpenCSV in order to write csv i'm using the CSVBindByName annotation this way:

```
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Date")
    private Long date;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Post content")
    private String text;
```

But in the generated file the headers are all in UPPERCASE:
DATE, POST CONTENT

Is there any way to generate the exact name in the annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that the CsvBindByName annotation always converts the column name to UpperCase based on the OpenCSV source code @ https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/bean/HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java#l210

You can try to use custom converter as detailed out here:

[OpenCsv writes wrong column names with BeanToCsv + HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778223/opencsv-writes-wrong-column-names-with-beantocsv-headercolumnnametranslatemapp)

Comment: Thanks. I had some issues with the proposed answers but your reference to the problem in the code help me to extend it and fix there what i needed.