# Why opencsv capitalizing csv headers while writing to file

Tags: java, opencsv

While writing Beans to CSV file by using OpenCSV 4.6, all the headers are changing to uppercase. Eventhough bean has @CsvBindByName annotation it is changing to uppercase.

Java Bean:

```java
public class ProjectInfo implements Serializable {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "ProjectName",required = true)
    private String projectName;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "ProjectCode",required = true)
    private String projectCode;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "Visibility",required = true)
    private String visibility;
    //setters and getters
}
```

Main method

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Collection<Serializable> projectInfos = getProjectsInfo();
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.csv"))){
        StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder builder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer);
        StatefulBeanToCsv beanWriter = builder
                    .withSeparator(';')
                    .build();
        try {
              beanWriter.write(projectInfos.iterator());
              writer.flush();

         } catch (CsvDataTypeMismatchException | CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException  e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to download admin file");
            }
        }

    }
```

Expected Result:

```
"ProjectCode";"ProjectName";"Visibility"
"ANY";"Country DU";"1"
"STD";"Standard";"1"
"TST";"Test";"1"
"CMM";"CMMTest";"1"
```

**Acutal Result:**

```
"PROJECTCODE";"PROJECTNAME";"VISIBILITY"
"ANY";"Country DU";"1"
"STD";"Standard";"1"
"TST";"Test";"1"
"CMM";"CMMTest";"1"
```

I don't have option to use ColumnMappingStrategy because I have to build this method as a generic solution. 
can anyone suggest me how to write the headers as it is?

Comment: Very bad. That's why OpenCSV sucks. Basically the ` @CsvBindByName` are useless

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It happens, because the code in [HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/bean/HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java) uses `toUpperCase()` for storing and retrieving the field names.

You could use the [HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/bean/HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy.java) instead and create the mapping by reflection.

```java
    
    public class AnnotationStrategy extends HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy
    {
        public AnnotationStrategy(Class<?> clazz)
        {
            Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
            //To prevent the column sorting
            List<String> originalFieldOrder=new ArrayList<>();
            for(Field field:clazz.getDeclaredFields())
            {
                CsvBindByName annotation = field.getAnnotation(CsvBindByName.class);
                if(annotation!=null)
                {
                    map.put(annotation.column(),annotation.column());
                    originalFieldOrder.add(annotation.column());
                }
            }
            setType(clazz);
            setColumnMapping(map);
            //Order the columns as they were created
            setColumnOrderOnWrite((a,b) -> Integer.compare(originalFieldOrder.indexOf(a), originalFieldOrder.indexOf(b)));
        }
        
        @Override
        public String[] generateHeader(Object bean) throws CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException
        {
            String[] result=super.generateHeader(bean);
            for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++)
            {
                result[i]=getColumnName(i);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

And, assuming that there is only one class of items (and always at least one item), the creation of `beanWriter` has to be expanded:

```java
StatefulBeanToCsv beanWriter = builder.withSeparator(';')
    .withMappingStrategy(new AnnotationStrategy(projectInfos.iterator().next().getClass()))
    .build();
```

Comment: Can I specify by using annotations at field level?

Comment: Look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778223/opencsv-writes-wrong-column-names-with-beantocsv-headercolumnnametranslatemapp), it's the inverse problem of yours.

Comment: In that solution they know which headers to map for example 'COLUMN1'->'name', but  here I will get headers dynamically so I can't create map.

Comment: if  the field names are not as same as column names in @CsvBindByName then we have to change the map to take key and value both should be **annotation.column()**. If we use  **annotation.column()** for both key and value then it will solve all the problems. Thanks a lot your answer, it helped me a lot.

Comment: I have used your solution it is useful to me like it has converted headers in lower case but it also sorted my headers in ASC order I dont want to change order of my headers.. can you please help me with this

Comment: @TirthTimaniya I've added some code to prevent the auto sorting. It's untested, so it may need some additional care.

Comment: Basically this library is useless if you have to write half of the code to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, [HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy uses](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/bean/HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java) toUpperCase() for storing and retrieving the field names.
In order to use custom field name you have to annotate you field with @CsvBindByName

```
@CsvBindByName(column = "Partner Code" )
private String partnerCode;
```

By default it will be capitalized to  PARTNER CODE because of the above reason.
so, in order to take control over it we have to write a class implementing [HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/bean/HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy.java). With csv 5.0 and java8 i have implemented like this

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;
import com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException;

public class AnnotationStrategy<T> extends HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<T> {
    Map<String, String> columnMap = new HashMap<>();
    public AnnotationStrategy(Class<? extends T> clazz) {

        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            CsvBindByName annotation = field.getAnnotation(CsvBindByName.class);
            if (annotation != null) {

                    columnMap.put(field.getName().toUpperCase(), annotation.column());
            }
        }
        setType(clazz);      
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        String name = headerIndex.getByPosition(col);
        return name;
    }

    public String getColumnName1(int col) {
        String name = headerIndex.getByPosition(col);
        if(name != null) {
            name = columnMap.get(name);
        }
        return name;
    }
    @Override
    public String[] generateHeader(T bean) throws CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException {
        String[] result = super.generateHeader(bean);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = getColumnName1(i);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used your solution it is useful to me like it has converted headers in lower case but it also sorted my headers in ASC order I dont want to change order of my headers.. can you please help me with this

Comment: @TirthTimaniya, I just saw your comment. Hope you have got the solution

Answer (score 2):

I have tried other solutions but it doesn't work when the property name and column name are not the same.

I am using 5.6. My solution is to reuse the strategy.

```java
public class CsvRow {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "id")
    private String id;

    // Property name and column name are different
    @CsvBindByName(column = "country_code")
    private String countryCode;

}
```

```java
// We are going to reuse this strategy
HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<CsvRow> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
strategy.setType(CsvRow.class);

// Build the header line which respects the declaration order
// So its value will be "id,country_code"
String headerLine = Arrays.stream(CsvRow.class.getDeclaredFields())
        .map(field -> field.getAnnotation(CsvBindByName.class))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(CsvBindByName::column)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

// Let the library to initialize column details in the strategy
try (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(headerLine);
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(stringReader)) {
    CsvToBean<CsvRow> csv = new CsvToBeanBuilder<CsvRow>(reader)
            .withType(CsvRow.class)
            .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
            .build();
    for (CsvRow csvRow : csv) {}
}
```

The strategy is ready for writing csv file.

```
try (OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of("test.csv"));
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)) {

    StatefulBeanToCsv<CsvRow> csv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<CsvRow>(writer)
        .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
        .withThrowExceptions(true)
        .build();

    csv.write(csvRows);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using opencsv 5.0 and Java 8, I had to modify AnnotationStrategy class code as follows to had it compiled :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;
import com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException;

public class AnnotationStrategy<T> extends HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<T> {
    public AnnotationStrategy(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            CsvBindByName annotation = field.getAnnotation(CsvBindByName.class);
            if (annotation != null) {
                map.put(annotation.column(), annotation.column());
            }
        }
        setType(clazz);
        setColumnMapping(map);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] generateHeader(T bean) throws CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException {
        String[] result = super.generateHeader(bean);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = getColumnName(i);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```