# Avoid repetition of header columns while using opencsv

Tags: java, filewriter, opencsv

I am using opencsv to append Java beans to a csv file. I'm using the following code  :

```
public void functionOne(String pathToFile, List<Bookings> bookings){
    FileWriter writer  = new FileWriter(pathToFile, true);
    StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<Bookings> builder=
                    new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer);

    StatefulBeanToCsv beanWriter = builder.build();
    beanWriter.write(bookings);
    writer.close();

}
```

This method will be called multiple times in my workflow ( hence I want the append flag to be true ). Things are getting appended to csv, **however**, for each call, the headers ( which are properties of the objects ) are getting repeated as well which is an issue. Any suggestions?

For reference, the csv looks like this :

```
property1    property2  property3
value1.1     value1.2   value1.3
property1    property2  property3
value2.1     value2.2   value2.3
```

Expected csv :

```
property1    property2  property3
value1.1     value1.2   value1.3
value2.1     value2.2   value2.3
```

Comment: You can try to create a Hashmap with property 1 as a key and value as a list. Something like this Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

Comment: Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168094/why-opencsv-capitalizing-csv-headers-while-writing-to-file